# Date picker field type - quickly select year?

Tags: field, datetime

I need a "date of birth" field. Out of the box, the date picker only allows moving left/right by month, which doesn't work for selecting years.

Is there a way to configure the date picker that Craft uses? Or is there a better way to make a date of birth chooser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this by populating a dropdown field using the [Dynamic Fields](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields) plugin. Here's the code I used to generate the dropdown options:

```
{% set maxYear = now|date_modify('+3 years')|date('Y') %}
{% for year in maxYear..1945 %}
    { "value": "{{ year }}", "label": "{{ year }}" }
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

*Update:*
Re-reading your question I just noticed that you might not only need a year picker. Well you could add two more dropdown fields for months and days (1-31) or you just teach your client to input the date into the normal Date/Time field with the keyboard.

Comment: I was considering Dynamic Fields already (and putting 3 of them in a SuperTable to avoid using too much space). It would be nice to store the date in a single field though (and in proper date format). Thanks for the code!

Comment: You could use the Preparse plugin to combine it to a single field. That's actually a good idea, especially if you're using the dropdowns in a Super Table / Matrix. Makes it easy to output in the template or even use the field as a field parameter in a criteria model.

Comment: Good idea - being able to store age directly as a field. I'll add the final code as an answer for anyone dealing with a similar situation.

Comment: Don't store the age. Store the day in 2015-10-30 format and you can use Twig's `date` filter in your templates to output in any format you want, even the weekday.

Comment: Added as an option in comment.

Answer (score 3):

Using carlcs's idea, I put three LJ Dynamic Dropdowns in a SuperTable, here's the code for each dropdown (day, month, year):

```
{% for day in 1..31 %}
    { "value": "{{ day }}", "label": "{{ day }}" }
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for month in 1..12 %}
    { "value": "{{ month }}", "label": "{{ month }}" }
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% set maxYear = now|date_modify('-15 years')|date('Y') %}
{% for year in maxYear..1925 %}
    { "value": "{{ year }}", "label": "{{ year }}" }
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then I added a Preparse field that joins these three dropdowns into a date string on each save (I have this under a User, so adapt to Entry/Asset/etc. if you need to).

```
{% spaceless %}
{% if user.userDateOfBirth | length %}

    {% set dateString = user.userDateOfBirth[0].year ~ '-' ~ user.userDateOfBirth[0].month ~ '-' ~ user.userDateOfBirth[0].day %}
    {{ dateString }}

{% endif  %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

To calculate age in my template, I use this little snippet (date("2015-07-06") will return a DateTime object so we can use the diff function on it).

```
{% set ageString = date(dateString).diff(now).format('%y') %}
```